# Consulta como llenar edittext en distintos fragment

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien, avanzo con el proyecto de fragment, ya realice los cinco fragment, ahora en el primer fragment llamado datos, se digita un registro el cual ya fue ingresado con anterioridad en los maestros de la base de datos, en el cual se traen algunos datos y de los cuales por ejemplo según código que presento este debe ser llenado en el segundo fragment llamado asegurado y así con otros fragment.

```
txtregistro1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.**/oficina/buscar_casos4.php?ID=" + txtregistro1.getText().toString();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            txtsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Siniestro"));
                            txtregistro1.setText(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                            txtpoliza.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Poliza"));
                            txtfechadenuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                            txtfechadesignacion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Designacion"));
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                            Fragment asegurado = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("asegurado");
                            if (asegurado == null){
                                return;
                            } else {
                                EditText txtnombre = asegurado.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
                                txtnombre.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Asegurado"));
                            }

                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });
```

lo que pretendo es que en el txtnombre que se encuentra en el segundo fragment llamado asegurado, cargue el dato del "nombre_asegurado" y así con otros más, pero no lo realiza y se queda haciendo loop, no sé qué puedo estar fallando ojala que me puedan asesorar y desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: No se entiende bien cuál es el problema. Y, si esperas varios datos (lo digo porque intentas leer un `JSONArray` y usas un bucle `for`), lo propio sería meter los datos en un `RecyclerView`, no en un `EditText`. Lo que hará ese código, en caso de que funcione, será poner en el `EditText` el último elemento del bucle, lo cual no tiene demasiado sentido.

Comment: @A.Cedano maestro lo que pretendo hacer es lo siguente que al momento de digitar el txtregistro1, me traiga los datos en distintos fragment, a lo mejor no me explique muy bien y de ser así te pido mis disculpas de antemano y como he dicho anteriormente,  soy nuevo en estas lides y me gusta seguir aprendiendo, esto mismo lo realizo en un acticity y funciona, pero ahora quierto hacerlo en fragment, ojala que me puedas asesorar y ayudar en esta consulta y disculpa las molestias de antemano si te confundio y te causo extrañesa mi consulta y desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: @A.Cedano realice unos cambios con  el ciclo for, que me recomendaste así que lo cambie, y lo que pretendo es hacer que en el txtnombre que se declara como edittext que se encuentra en el fragment denominado asegurado, cargue el nombre, ojala que me puedas asesorar, por lo cual favor de ver el nuevo código

Comment: les comento que realice una prueba paso a paso y me arrojo el siguiente error: "java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.getView()' on a null object reference", en la línea del getview.

Answer (score 0):

cambie un poco el código de la búsqueda en el cual me mencionaban del ciclo for, que no era muy conveniente, por lo cual quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
txtregistro1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String url = "http://192.168.1.89/oficina/buscar_casos4.php?ID=" + txtregistro1.getText().toString();
            JsonArrayRequest jsonArrayRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
                    if (response.length() > 0) {
                        try {
                            jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(0);
                            txtsiniestro.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Siniestro"));
                            txtregistro1.setText(jsonObject.getString("ID"));
                            txtpoliza.setText(jsonObject.getString("N_Poliza"));
                            txtfechadenuncia.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Denuncia"));
                            txtfechadesignacion.setText(jsonObject.getString("Fecha_Designacion"));
                            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                            Fragment seguro = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("asegurado");
                            EditText txtnombre = seguro.getView().findViewById(R.id.txtnombre);
                            txtnombre.setText(jsonObject.getString("Nombre_Asegurado"));
                        } catch (JSONException e){
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Este Registro no ha sido ingresado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        txtpoliza.requestFocus();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Error de conexión", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getActivity());
            requestQueue.add(jsonArrayRequest);
        }
    });
```

ahora si se dan cuenta en la loinea donde declaro el nombre del fragment, tengo la soghuiente duda, si coloco en el nombre del xml o del java, y lo otro leyendo algunos artículos que encontré en estos casos siempre hablan de recargar el fragment de nuevo o de inicializar, ojala que me puedan ayudar y desde ya muchas gracias.